# Domain of complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm totally new to complex analysis topic.

Consider the complex function,

$$ f(z) = \frac{\ln(z^2)}{\exp(iz)+1}$$

What is the domain of analyticity of this function?

Also I am wondering how should I sketch it?

Comment: Generally we don't sketch complex functions, because they require 4d graph paper and that is in short supply.

Do you have a definition of "analytic" or sense of what it means?  The short answer is that you still can't divide by 0.

Comment: Do you want to "sketch the function" or sketch its domain?  Also, in addition to removing the origin and the poles of the denominator, you'll want to select a branch cut and remove that too!

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to visualize a complex function.

In Mathematica, you can easily do the visualization.(with heights, colors, vectors, etc.)

Here is an example.

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[z^2]/(Exp[I*z] + 1), {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> 300, MeshStyle -> {White, Black}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Re[#2] &, Im[#2] &}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "GlobalAbs"]
```

[image]

In the figure,
at point$(x_0,y_0)$

- height represents the Abs of $f(x_0+jy_0)$
- as the PlotLegends shows,(Color hue?) means Arg of $f(x_0+jy_0)$,(Color brightness?) means Abs of $f(x_0+jy_0)$
- the white line means, in the same line Re of $f(x_0+jy_0)$ are equal
- the black line means, in the same line Im of $f(x_0+jy_0)$ are equal;

Answer (score -1):

The domain of this function is the entire complex plane without the origin, because $\ln$ is not defined there, and every point where $e^{iz}=-1$, because this would cause division by $0$. Thus, the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb C\backslash(\{0\}\cup\{2\pi n+\pi:n\in\Bbb Z\}).$

Although difficult, as stated in Doug M's comment, it is possible to sketch complex functions, albeit in a roundabout way. To sketch it, you can sketch the level surfaces of $\text{Re}[f(z)]$, $\text{Im[f(z)]}$, and $|f(z)|.$ This is what wolfram alpha often does to demonstrate simply the behavior of complex functions, for example $\ln(z)$:

[image]

Of course, they have colors, but you'll be conveying similar information by drawing level curves.

Comment: You also need to remove from the domain the points where $\log(z^2)$ is not analytic.